# Where can I find information on the Spell ID for a spell used by the WoW API?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, mods

I need to know what the spell id is supposed to be for certain spells for my WoW addon, but I'm not sure where to find information on the spells.

Is there a goto list somewhere?

I read on wowwiki that wowhead has this information, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: I answered your question. However, this question would be more appropriate to ask on the [Game Development SE Site](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). Since spell IDs aren't anything you need to know to play the game better, such information isn't a good fit for this site. Since it would help you develop an add-on for the game, however, it would be great for Game Development. :)

Comment: Going to disagree Shaun. While Joseph clearly *is* making an addon, there are any number of reasons that a typical player could want the specific spell ID without needing to develop an addon. Not least of which, it's one of the best ways to reduce the number of characters in a very long macro!

Comment: I'm with @Less on this one, it has in game uses (as well as development ones).

Comment: thanks @Shaun, I didn't even realize there was a stackexchange just for game dev!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you search for a spell on Wowhead, the ID will be in the URL.

Example: Searching for [Shield Bash](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=72) gets you a page with the URL of http://www.wowhead.com/spell=72. The part after 'spell=' (in other words, 72) is the ID of the spell.

Its also worth noting that you can link spells in game via:

`/script DEFAULT_CHAT_FRAME:AddMessage("\124cff71d5ff\124Hspell:72\124h[Shield Bash]\124h\124r");`

where spell:## is the spell id